# Explaining percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I was helping my sister learn percentages. We've got a simple exercise: product X costs $153.75$ including 23% tax. Calculate price without tax.

Now, the answer is of course to solve $1.23x = 153.75$. She however tried another way: $153.75 - 0.23 \cdot 153.75 = x$ with intuition to just subtract the tax from price. This is obviously wrong. I showed her the right way and we worked another example where the tax was 100% (and where the error is obvious).

She now *knows* that the second way is wrong, she *sees* the numbers that come out... but she told me that she still does not understand *why* exactly the second method does not work. And I couldn't find a way to explain this without using examples with specific numbers.

Question: How to explain this problem?

Comment: Did you tell her that you need to take 23% on what you call $x$ and not $153.75$? From the way she subtracts, it seems that she thinks that the 23% is on $153.75$.

Comment: Also $0.76(1.23x)$ $\neq$ $x$. That would imply that 0.76 is the inverse of 1.23, which it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, it would be difficult to explain without specific numbers, but I'll give it a try. The original price gets a tax added, giving the total price. The tax added is a given percent of the original. When she subtracted the same percent from the total price, she was getting what the tax would be on the total price, a larger number than the tax on just the original price.

Let me try WITH numbers.  :-)
If the original price is $\$100$ (to make it easy), and the tax is 10% (again easy numbers), then the total price is $\$110$. The problem with taking the 'tax' back off of the total, trying to get back to the original, is that we would now subtract $\$11$ from the total, getting an 'original' price of only $\$99$. Tax on the original is not the same as tax on the larger total price.

Answer (score 2):

23% of $x$ is smaller than 23% of the larger quantity 153.75.

Answer (score 2):

Use distributivity (if she understands that)

Adding tax is $\text{price} + \text{tax}\cdot \text{price}$

In other words after applying distributivity: $\text{price}\cdot(1+\text{tax})$

Then you'll need to explain that $\dfrac{1}{1+\text{tax}} \neq(1-\text{tax})$

Or make the mistake really obvious:

You have $\text{taxedprice} = \text{price} + \text{tax}\cdot\text{price}$

She tried to solve price with $\text{price} = \text{taxedprice} - \text{tax}\cdot\text{taxedprice}$

Fill in the original $\text{taxedprice}$ in the formula and you'll get $\text{price} = (\text{price} + \text{tax}\cdot\text{price})- \text{tax}\cdot\text(\text{price} + \text{tax}\cdot\text{price})$ or $\text{price} = \text{price} + \text{tax}\cdot\text{price}- \text{tax}\cdot\text{price} -\text{tax}\cdot\text{tax}\cdot\text{price}$. Which would mean that $0 = -\text{tax}\cdot\text{tax}\cdot\text{price}$

Comment: You can write $\text{tax}\cdot\text{price}$ or $\text{tax}\times\text{price}$.  Using an asterisk for ordinary multiplication is a workaround for occasions when one is limited to the characters on the keyboard.  Its use in MathJax or LaTeX or the like is vulgar. ${}\qquad{}$